# 'SDWebImageCompat.h' file not found error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, sdwebimage

I'm having this error with my SDWebImage library  'SDWebImageCompat.h' file not found   from since I install this pod every day I face new error yesterday it was work fine I didn't even touch any file or change his location know I have these error I search for this error and I didn't found a solution 
i'm using xcode last version 9 swift 4 i didn't install SDWebImage with version just   pod 'SDWebImage'

Comment: Mention your current xCode version, swift version and SDWebImage version you are using now

Comment: edits have been made

Comment: Latest xCode version is 9.2 . Once you install pod file through terminal, It will be print SDWebImage version.
Make sure, you are using the latest one

Comment: look man it's the last one I'm sure but even that not fixing my problem every bod is auto install the last V

Comment: You are opening workspace and not project?

Comment: yes I'm opening workspace

Answer (score 5):

Remove folder with SDWebImage in Finder and run `pod install`. In my case some files of this pod were missing on filesystem.